# Python regex keep a few more tokens

Tags: python, regex

I am using the following regex in Python to keep words that do not contain non alphabetical characters:

```
(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?!\S)|(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?=:(?!\S))
```

The problem is that this regex does not keep words that I would like to keep such as the following:

```
Company,
months.
third-party
```

In other words I would like to keep words that are followed by a comma, a dot, or have a dash between two words.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

I tried adding something like `|(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?=\.(?!\S))` for the dots but it does not seem to be working.

Thanks !

EDIT:

Should match these:

```
On-line
.   These
maintenance,
other.
.  Our
Google
```

Should NOT match these:

```
MFgwCgYEVQgBAQICAf8DSgAwRwJAW2sNKK9AVtBzYZmr6aGjlWyK3XmZv3dTINen
NY7xtb92dCTfvEjdmkDrUw==
$As_Of_12_31_20104206http://www.sec.gov/CIK0001393311instant2010-12-31T00:00:000001-01-01T00:00:00falsefalseArlington/S.Cooper
-Publisher
gaap_RealEstateAndAccumulatedDepreciationCostsCapitalizedSubsequentToAcquisitionCarryingCostsus
```

At the moment I am using the following python code to read a text file line by line:

```
find_words = re.compile(r'(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?!\S)|(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?=:(?!\S))').findall
```

then i open the text file

```
contents = open("test.txt","r")
```

and I search for the words line by line for line in contents:

```
if find_words(line.lower()) != []: lineWords=find_words(line.lower()) 
print "The words in this line are: ", lineWords
```

using some word lists in the following way:

```
wanted1 = set(find_words(open('word_list_1.csv').read().lower()))
wanted2 = set(find_words(open('word_list_2.csv').read().lower()))
negators = set(find_words(open('word_list_3.csv').read().lower()))
```

i first want to get the valid words from the .txt file, and then check if these words belong in the word lists. the two steps are independent.

Comment: These words [are not even matched with your regex](https://regex101.com/r/uY1kZ8/1). Please add full sample input and expected output.

Comment: I would like to change the regex so that I keep these words this is the question

Comment: Do you want to match the words with the trailing point/comma, or without?

Comment: without the point/comma

Comment: post some examples for valid and invalid matches..

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/bS3pV8/2) regex the one you're looking for?

Comment: @Jerry your regex does not capture `"expects," expressions. .  These "Risk Factors" (“SEC”)` which I would also like to capture

Comment: @adrCoder checkout the edit

Comment: all_words = wanted1|wanted2|negators this is not correct. first I want to get all the valid words, then to check if these words belong in these lists or not... all_words could be taken from nltk

Comment: @adrCoder Ok, a bit wonky in my eye, but [that one](https://regex101.com/r/bS3pV8/3) looks a bit closer to what you seem to be looking for. I removed the non-word parts from the matches as I just saw your above comment about needing the words without them.

Comment: How can I write your regex to replace `find_words = re.compile(r'(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?!\S)|(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?=:(?!\S))').findall` so that I try it ?

Comment: @adrCoder Like this: `find_words = re.compile(r'(?:(?<=[^\w-./])|(?<=^))[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+)*(?=\W|$)').findall`

Comment: I get an error in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range

Comment: @adrCoder Just would mention that because of the urls, I had to add `/` to the 'restricted' characters before a word. That this implies is `red/blue` will match `red` but fail to match `blue`. If there is another way to distinguish the urls and the non-urls before, that shouldn't be a problem. And on the last error, apologies, I don't know why the site doesn't see that as an error. The following should be better: `find_words = re.compile(r'(?:(?<=[^\w./-])|(?<=^))[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+)*(?=\W|$)').findall`

Comment: Hi Jerry. Your regex seems to be the closest to what I want to achieve for now. You should post an answer explaining a bit how its parts work, and I will accept it as the best answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this regex:

```
find_words = re.compile(r'(?:(?<=[^\w./-])|(?<=^))[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+)*(?=\W|$)').findall
```

There are 3 parts from your initial regex that I changed:

Middle part:

```
[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+)*
```

This allows hyphenated words.

The last part:

```
(?=\W|$)
```

This is a bit similar to `(?!\S)` except that it allows for characters that are not spaces like punctuations as well. So what happens is, this will allow a match if, after the word matched, the line ends, or there is a non-word character, in other words, there are no letters or numbers or underscores (if you don't want `word_` to match `word`, then you will have to change `\W` to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`).

The first part (probably most complex):

```
(?:(?<=[^\w./-])|(?<=^))
```

It is composed of two parts itself which matches either `(?<=[^\w./-])` or `(?<=^)`. The second one allows a match if the line begins before the word to be matched. We cannot use `(?<=[^\w./-]|^)` because python's lookbehind from `re` cannot be of variable width (with `[^\w./-]` having a length of 1 and `^` a length of 0).

`(?<=[^\w./-])` allows a match if, before the word, there are no word characters, periods, forward slashes or hyphens.

When broken down, the small parts are rather straightforward I think, but if there's anything you want some more elaboration, I can give more details.

Comment: I accept it and if I need more help I will let you know and hopefully you will help me again :) thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This is not a regex task because you can not detect the words with regext.You must have a dictionary to check your words.

So i suggest use regex to split your string with non-alphabetical characters and check if the all of items exist in your dictionary.for example :

```
import re

words=re.split(r'\S+',my_string)
print all(i in my_dict for i in words if i)
```

As an alter native you can use [`nltk.corups` as your dictionary](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.html) :

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
words=re.split(r'\S+',my_string)
if all(wordnet.synsets(word) for i in words if i):
       #do stuff
```

But if you want to use yourself word list you need to change your regex because its incorrect instead use `re.split` as preceding :

```
all_words = wanted1|wanted2|negators

with open("test.txt","r") as f :
  for line in f :
     for word in line.split():
        words=re.split(r'\S+',word)
        if all(i in all_words for i in words if i):
            print word
```

Comment: can you give me an example of how to use that nltk corpus. at the moment i am doing `find_words = re.compile(r'(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?!\S)|(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?=:(?!\S))').findall` then i open the text file `contents = open("test.txt","r")` and I search for the words line by line `for line in contents:
   if find_words(line.lower()) != []:
    lineWords=find_words(line.lower())
    print "The words in this line are: ", lineWords` how I can use your code to try it out ?

Comment: @adrCoder `wordnet` is one of the `NLTK`'s corups that you need to first install `NLTK` then the `wordnet-corups` its a dictionary that approximately is contain 200k word! and if you think you need such thing i recommended that, otherwise i don't suggest using `NLTK`

Comment: @adrCoder then all you need is splitting your string based on none-alphabetical characters then check for those existence within a dictionary!

Comment: Kasra could you please explain how I could use the nltk by adjusting the code I am currently using, since I use the find_words function and I am confused on how to adapt it to use the nltk?

Comment: @adrCoder Your function is wrong! you want to match `On-line` but for example not `Onli-ne` right?

Comment: How can I fix it using your code? Or else I can not check your code to see if it does what I want to do !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78513/discussion-between-adrcoder-and-kasra).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using all sorts of complicated look-arounds, you can use `\b` to detect the boundary of words. This way, you can use e.g. `\b[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*\b`

Example:

```
>>> p = r"\b[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*\b"
>>> text = "This is some example text, with some multi-hyphen-words and invalid42 words in it."
>>> re.findall(p, text)
['This', 'is', 'some', 'example', 'text', 'with', 'some', 'multi-hyphen-words', 'and', 'words', 'in', 'it']
```

Update: Seems like this does not work too well, as it also detects fragments from URLs, e.g. `www`, `sec` and `gov` from `http://www.sec.gov`.

Instead, you might try this variant, using look-around explicitly stating the 'legal' characters:

```
r"""(?<![^\s("])[a-zA-Z]+(?:[-'][a-zA-Z]+)*(?=[\s.,:;!?")])"""
```

This seems to [pass all your test-cases](https://regex101.com/r/uU6yU0/6).

Let's dissect this regex:

- `(?<![^\s("])` - look-behind asserting that the word is preceeded by space, quote or parens, but e.g. not a number (using double-negation instead of positive look-behind so the first word is matched, too)
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - the first part of the word
- `(?:[-'][a-zA-Z]+)*` - optionally more word-segments after a `'` or `-`
- `(?=[\s.,:;!?")])` - look-ahead asserting that the word is followed by space, punctuation, quote or parens

Comment: i saw your edit. I would also like to capture .  We ( i.e. it doesn't capture words when preceded by a dot and a whitespace). I would also like to capture words inside " " such as “Public Storage” and words in a parenthesis such as (locks, or supplies) (as you can see the parenthesis can be left or right).

Comment: a few more that I would like to capture : .  These (“SEC”) Storage's

Comment: @adrCoder The `'` should be easy to add. But what do you mean with `. These`? Should `Stuff. More Stuff? Stuff` yield `['Stuff', '. More', 'Stuff', '? Stuff']`?

Comment: In case that `. These` is found then `These` should be kept. `Stuff. More Stuff? Stuff` should yield `['Stuff', 'More', 'Stuff', 'Stuff']`

Comment: @adrCoder "In case that . These is found then These should be kept." Doesn't my regex already do that?

Comment: If i am not mistaken `? Stuff` does not keep `Stuff`